# No sound/playback when JACK bridge is on

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

i want to use JACK(Cadence) to get my system sound output into PROCESSING(the JAVA language) to process it there with MINIM. But i can't even setup JACK. When I start it I can't play any media at all - videos are not even playing muted.

I use an onboard Soundchip and my distro is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

My user is in audio group.
In Cadence there is a red symbol with an exclamation mark at "Current kernel: (!) 5.13.0 Generic"
I cannot set the Clock source to anything in the Engine Settings. I check "system" and next time i open the settings it's unchecked again.

I tried to change the input/output device. There is only one other option: hw:PCH,0 [ALC3202 Analog]

Any idea how i can fix this? Thank you in advance

Screenshots:

[image: JACK Settings Engine]
[image: JACK Settings Driver]
[image: Catia]
[image: Cadence]

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated. It should report .4, not .3. This means you're missing lots of updates.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your response. It's now updated but the problem is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I had to change the input/output device in the general Ubuntu Sound Settings. Sorry.